# Async/Await not working as expected with Promise.all and a .map function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I have a slew of `async` functions I'm using and I'm having a weird issue.

My code, working, looks like:

```
async mainAsyncFunc (metadata) {
  let files = metadata.map(data => this.anotherAsyncFunc(data.url));
  return Promise.all(files);
}
```

`anotherAsyncFunc` function looks like:

```
  async anotherAsyncFunc (url) {
    return await axios({
      url,
    }).then(res => res.data)
      .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });
  }
```

My issue comes when I try to append more data to what the first function (`mainAsyncFunc`) returns. My thoughts are to do that in the `map`, naturally, and when all is said and done, modified it looks like:

```
async mainAsyncFunc (metadata) {
    files = metadata.map(data => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          let file = this.anotherAsyncFunc(data.download_url);
          let fileName = data.name;
          resolve({
            file,
            fileName
          });
        });
      });
    return Promise.all(files);
}
```

If it's not clear, I'm getting the file itself like normal, and appending a fileName to it, then resolving that object back.

For some reason, this is returning a pending Promise, whereas I would expect it to wait for them to be fulfilled and then returned as a complete file and name in an object. Any help understanding what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `async` functions return promises. Nor can you turn a Promise-wrapped value into an ordinary value, you will always have to `await` or call `.then`. Why did you expect to get an array?

Comment: @JaredSmith I use `Promise.all()` because I'm mapping over a dataset and returning the result of async function for each item. Thus creating an array. However, I just solved my own issue and am posting a solution now

Comment: `Promise.all` returns a Promise. Again, you *cannot 'unwrap' a promise*. You can only `.then` it.

Comment: @JaredSmith I can assure you my working code is returning an array of fulfilled objects :). If it helps you understand it better, I call this function like: `FileRetriever.mainAsyncFunc(metadata).then(contents => ...)`, and with my new working code `contents` is an array.

Comment: No, its not, your code does not work the way you seem to think it does. `await` is sugar over `.then`. You cannot ever unwrap a promise. Its a logical impossibility in the general case, as *there is no way* to tell if a promise is resolved or not.

Comment: Handy tip: Any time you find yourself using `new Promise` when the values you're working with are already promises, it usually means you've got something wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you've solved your issue, just as a bit of a pointer, you can further simplify your code as follows:

```
async anotherAsyncFunc (url) {
    return (await axios({ url })).data;
}

async mainAsyncFunc (metadata) {
    let files = metadata.map(async data => ({
        file: await this.anotherAsyncFunc(data.download_url),
        fileName: data.name
    }));

    return Promise.all(files);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just solved the issue:

```
  files = metadata.map(async (data) => {
    let file = await this.anotherAsyncFunction(data.download_url);
    let fileName = data.name;
    return {
      file,
      fileName
    };
  });
```

I needed to wrap the anonymous function in `async` so I could use `await` inside of it. Hopefully this helps anyone else with a similar problem!