# How do I wait for one http call to finish before the next http call runs with an argument retrieved from the first http call?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http

I'm trying to hit one api to retrieve a specific string which is then stored in a variable and passed to another http api call but the problem is the api call that needs the argument runs and never sends the correct request. (noobie here btw)

here are the two calls, removed some personal info from it but it still makes sense.

```
async getMatches() {
    return this.http.get('matchesUrl', {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer **'
      }
    })
  }

  async getMatchStats(matchId: string) {
    return this.http.get(`specificMatchUrl/${matchId}/`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer **'
      }
    })
  }
```

And here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GetapiService} from '../getapi.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gamingpage',
  templateUrl: './gamingpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gamingpage.component.scss']
})
export class GamingpageComponent implements OnInit {

  title = '';
  wins = '';
  totalMatches = '';
  currentWinStreak = '';
  latestMap = '';
  matchId = '';
  constructor(
    private api: GetapiService
  ) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getPlayerStats().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.title = data['game_id'];
      this.wins = data.lifetime['Wins']
      this.totalMatches = data.lifetime['Matches']
      this.currentWinStreak = data.lifetime['Current Win Streak']
    });

    (await this.api.getMatches()).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.matchId = data.items[0].match_id;
    });

    (await this.api.getMatchStats(this.matchId)).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.latestMap = data.rounds.round_stats['Map']
    })
  }

}
```

I thought that awaiting both calls would fix this because the getMatchStats won't run until getMatches is done and that matchId variable is stored. But when the call is made, the url is incorrect and doesn't contain the matchId. I've verified that console.log is showing it correctly so I must be doing something wrong but can't seem to figure out what. I'm looking at the similar questions but none seem to be doing the same thing as me... or at least what I understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, perhaps chain them together https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989718/how-to-chain-async-await-using-for-data-that-depends-on-the-first-call

Comment: hmm, await is for promise and http call return observer, you are mixing those 2 making it hard to read your code and also it's wrong to use them together that way. So I suggest you learn a bit about Observable or just remove all async/await all along, they're make no sense in your code.

Comment: if you want quick solution, here is the keyword for you, Promise.all for async/await and ForkJoin for Observer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not** use async await, use [switchMap rxjs operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

```
this.api.getMatches()).pipe(switchMap((data:any)=>{
   this.matchId =data.items[0].match_id;
   return this.api.getMatchStats(this.matchId)
})).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.latestMap = data.rounds.round_stats['Map'];
});
```

Angular is full plenty Observables, with rxjs operators we can transform / join /delay... observables. These oblige us to think in "async way", but really are great. The most important rxjs operators (but not all) are

1. forkJoin: join several observables and wait until all are
   completed
2. switchMap: transform one observable in another one that depend from
   the first
3. map: transform a response of an Observable
4. merge: create an observable that emit a value each time one of several
   observables emit one value

I know it's a bit complex, but it's necessary understand a bit about rxjs operators to use Angular

Answer (score 0):

Get your first call this.api.getMatches() in this strucure:

```
myObservable.subscribe(
  x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
  err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification')
);
```

Once you have done that put your second call in the onComplete statement

```
() => {
    (this.api.getMatchStats(this.matchId)).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.latestMap = data.rounds.round_stats['Map']
    })
}
```

So you code would look like the following

```
this.api.getMatches().subscribe(
  data => this.matchId = data.items[0].match_id;,
  err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  () => {this.api.getMatchStats(this.matchId)).subscribe(
         data => {this.latestMap = data.rounds.round_stats['Map']}
        )}
);
```

That sould do it. :)

Answer (score -1):

keep it simple :)

```
this.matchId = (await this.api.getMatches()).items[0].match_id;

this.latestMap = (await 
  this.api.getMatchStats(this.matchId)).rounds.round_stats['Map'];
```